# Java server socket not accepting connection over tethered connection

Tags: android, sockets, networking, android-wifi, wifip2p

I've written a small file transfer program for android using standard Java sockets. The program works fine except for the following case:
I connect two android devices A and B over WiFi tethering connection. Device A is sharing the connection (enabled as wireless hotspot). When I run java server on A and client on B, the program works okay but when I run the server on device B, it can't accept any socket binding request from A. It doesn't throw any exception. Seems like the request is not reaching the server! However, both the devices are connected (ping test is okay in both directions). Can't I run socket server on a device connected as hotspot client? I thought once the networking is setup correctly, the application would work in any direction.
Also, Wireshark traces reveal nothing. What am I missing here? Please help! Here are my code snippets:

Server side (waiting for client connection):

```
while (true) {
                    try {
                        socket = serversocket.accept();
                        Runnable connectionHandler = new ConnectionHandler(
                                socket, fileArray, filepathNameArray,
                                SenderActivity.this, userID, handler);
                        new Thread(connectionHandler).start();
                        userID = userID + 1;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

I would appreciate any kind of help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it does not connect then it makes no sense showing all that irrelevant copyFile code. Better show the code where the server socket waits for a connection.

Comment: I've edited my question. Please refer to the question now! Thanks :)

Comment: So you are sure that the line `Runnable connectionHandler = new ConnectionHandler(...` is not executed then?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure that connectionHandler is not called (I had inserted a connection info line just below socket binding line). Also, the wireshark shows no trace of outgoing message from my server!

Comment: Dit your hotspot test. It does not matter which of the two devices runs the server. It works both sides. The first try though failed. Messing around a bit did it.

Comment: That's exactly my point. The program works on some device pairs. But my problem is I can't even start troubleshooting as I don't know where to look for problem? :( The network packet trace shows request coming from client (which is a hotspot server in my case) but I find no response from server. Also, the request TCP packet looks okay..

Comment: At first I thought there might be a restriction on OS level (that the server can only work on device sharing the WiFi connection) but then again, the program works flawlessly on both directions for some device pairs.